# ASP.NET Core custom error pages with restricted access in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-10

I want to restrict access to my ASP.NET Core application by only configuring it in IIS (10).
This is not the problem, as I enable only "Windows authentication" and then I can do

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyDLL.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" >
      </aspNetCore>
      <security>
         <authorization>
           <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
           <add accessType="Allow" users="user.withaccess />
         </authorization>
       </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

This works fine, but every user without access just gets a 401 response and no error page.
Normally you could configure something like that:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <!-- ... -->
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">
            <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="401" subStatusCode="2" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="401.htm" responseMode="File" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

but the custom error page is only accessible by users who already can access the application (trying to open the error page results in a 401 too for unauthorized users).

Now in my case it's currently not possible to change the ASP.NET Core application itself, so I have to do it in IIS.

What do I have to configure that the custom error page can be served, but everything else is protected?

Comment: Try to not use execute url as the way to response custome error page. If you use windows authentication for whole site. The url of error page may also ask for credentials. Try to create a custome error page and store in another folder. Then set the IIS error page's path to that folder.